# ¿Cómo hacer un cuadrado responsivo con un ancho máximo?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Quiero crear una `div` que sea cuadrado y responsivo, es decir, que si se cambia el tamaño de la pantalla (o si cambia el dispositivo con el que se la página web) el cuadrado crezca/decrezca proporcionalmente, pero siempre con forma de cuadrado.

Para ello tengo el siguiente código con `padding-top`:

```css
.cuadrado {
  width:25%;
  height:0;
  padding-top:25%;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadrado"></div>
```

Eso funciona sin problemas hasta que intento limitar el tamaño del cuadrado con un `max-width`, entonces el ancho se limita pero no el `padding-top` lo que hace que la figura deje de ser un cuadrado y pase a ser un rectángulo en pantallas grandes:

```css
.cuadrado {
  width:25%;
  max-width:100px;
  height:0;
  padding-top:25%;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadrado"></div>
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el código para que la figura sea cuadrada siempre?¿Debería enfocarlo de otra manera en lugar de usando `padding-top` (que parece algo *hacky*)?

Comment: usando vh y vw? ya lo has probado?

Comment: El principal motivo para lo que busco es usarlo en dispositivos móviles. Si el soporte para móvil es amplio, me vale.

Comment: Lo único es que busco hacerlo sólo con HTML/CSS sin JavaScript

Comment: pero se deforma por que solo restringes lo ancho, no seria asi?  ` max-width:100px
  max-height:100px`

Comment: @x-rw en este caso `max-height` no funcionaría porque `height` es 0 que siempre será menor. Pero lo que mencionas de `vw`  sí que podría funcionar. Deberías ponerlo como respuesta (al menos te llevarías mi +1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `vh` quedaría siempre cuadrado

```css
.cuadrado {
  width:25vh;
  max-width:100px;
  height:25vh;
  max-height:100px;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadrado"></div>
```

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro funciona en el snipet, siempre queda cuadrado

Comment: Ahora sí. Gracias por la paciencia

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero no es lo suficiente adecuado para lo que necesitas?

Comment: Sí, de hecho se ajusta mejor a lo que necesito porque sólo tengo que cambiar el CSS y no la estructura HTML

Answer (score 1):

```css
.square {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;
  border-color:red;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

Pruébalo así

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con:

```
.cuadrado {
  width:25%;
  height:auto;
  padding-top:25%;
  position:relative;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Al ser height: auto, se ajusta automaticamente al width.

Comment: Este código tiene el mismo problema en cuanto se pone el `max-width` (ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/2cjozj50/)